# Error same site cookie error when trying to implement Google recaptcha v2.0 in Angular localhost

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja2n0.png)

I signed up for google Recaptcha and got my ID KEY and added the "localhost" to my allowed domains.
I installed this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-recaptcha to use google's reCaptchav2.0 and implemented it the same as it is there.

I already tried to put the cookie "SIDCC" with `sameSite: Lax` and `secure: True`
but after reloading the page a couple of times those options are automatically unchecked.

The Recaptcha shows up on the page and it works perfectly,but why does this cookie error appear? **should i ignore that?**

I'd appreciate your help.

[Edit: cookie settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8dX6.png)

Comment: Can you show the cookie settings?

This problem should be fixed with the `sameSite: Lax` and `secure: True` settings

Comment: I already tried but it is strange that it does not work :(, it keeps showing the same error. I edited the post by uploading the cookie settings.

Comment: after reloading the page a couple of times those options are automatically unchecked

Comment: Your app is deploy in localhost, and the protocol is HTTP.  In this case the cookie configuration `SameSite=None` ? Is only a idea.  My information is based in [this article](https://digiday.com/media/what-is-chrome-samesite/)

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have the same with v3 with 28 SameSite cookie error